# Passing x-ms-routing-name query parameter to app service through app gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We've deployed our api app on Azure with a private endpoint.  The service is accessible by a custom domain through our app gateway.  We'd like to take advantage of a [deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) we're calling 'release' but when testing using the x-ms-routing-name query parameter it doesn't work using the custom domain.

This works
https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/path/?x-ms-routing-name=release

But this doesn't
https://example.com/path/?x-ms-routing-name=release

Do we need to looking into rewrite rules in the app gateway or is there other configuration we need to look at first?

After taking a closer look at the cookie it only applies to the azure url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is facing this situation we resolved the issue by adding rewrite rules in our app gateway.

Added a condition to check if "x-ms-routing-name=release" is in the url query string
and if it is rewrite the response header and set the following cookie

```
x-ms-routing-name=release; path=/; HttpOnly; Max-Age=3600; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Add another rule to handle when x-ms-routing-name=self is in the url

[image: rewrite rules in Azure]